# mongoose app crashing giving const err = new MongooseError(message);

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i m writing code for a basic node js api and connecting to mongodb from mongoose to test if the data base is geting created and it keeps giving me this err

this is the code

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const app = express()
const port = 3000

// mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
// mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/tst',()=> console.log("db connected"));
const conn = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test')
conn.readyState;

const aviSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name : String,
  awsLink : String
})

const avi = mongoose.model("avi",aviSchema)

const Avi = new avi({
  name:"zahab",
  awsLink:"aws"
})
Avi.save()


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

this is the err
const err = new MongooseError(message);
^

```
MongooseError: Operation `avis.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\as comp\Desktop\node aws check\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:158:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)

Node.js v18.12.1
```